# с++: указать для класса интерфейс с методами так, чтобы не менять размера объекта класса

Tags: c++, классы, наследование, виртуальная-функция

подскажите, можно ли реализовать следующую идею:

есть интерфейс

```
class IBase {
public:
    virtual operator CData() const = 0;
}
```

есть соответствующий класс

```
class CChild : public IBase {
public:
    operator CData() const;

public:
    int m_data;
}
```

изначально (когда не было базового класса) через CChild считывались данные из файла (записанные в бинарном виде, т.е. блоками по `sizeof(CChild)`)

но затем, когда был введен базовый класс это стало невозможным, поскольку `virtual` увеличивает размер объекта на размер указателя (8байт для 64битной сборки)

**такой вопрос** - как обойти данную проблему

понятно, что можно

1. отказаться от наследования, но очень было хотелось показать, что у `CChild` обязательно должен быть метод `operator CData() const;` (ну отчасти из-за эстетических соображений, отчасти из-за того, что таких классов `CChildX` несколько и у каждого своя начинка, свои размеры, но у всех есть один и тот же обязательный метод)
2. не делать наследование от абстрактного класса (чтобы не было `virtual` методов), но тогда возникают проблемы с универсализацией использования :(

Подскажите как обычно выходят из данной проблемы?

Answer (score 2):

Из данной проблемы выходят **сериализацией**. Не нужно опираться на бинарное представление экземпляра класса в памяти для его хранения на диске. Даже в случае Plain Old Data (без виртуальности, наследования и разных модификаторов доступа) могут играть роль выравнивания, да и просто размеры конкретных полей данных (`sizeof(int)` может разниться от системы к системе). Поэтому, чтобы сохранять и в последствии загружать (заполнять) объекты надо использовать [сериализацию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). В текущем виде вопрос выглядит как [ошибка молотка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/176217).

Answer (score 0):

```
class CData{
};

class IBase {
public:
    virtual operator CData() const = 0;
};

class CChild {
public:
    operator CData() const;
public:
    int m_data;
};

class VCChild1 : public IBase , public CChild {
public:
    virtual operator CData() const {return CChild::operator CData();}
};

// или так

class VCChild2 : public IBase {
public :
  CChild c ;
  virtual operator CData() const {return CData(c);}
};
```

В файл записывать статический элемент объекта `static_cast<CChild&>` или  `CChild c ;`. А экземпляр с виртуальными функциями из класса `VCChild` будет работать.

Answer (score -1):

Наследование убрать, а наличие (и правильность сигнатуры) метода проверять концептом, или, до C++20, SFINAE.

Comment: В исходном вопросе поставлена задача именно с наследованием. Паллиативные способы с проверкой сигнатур не решают общую проблему заполнения структур сырыми данными (с учётом заполнений, big/little endian, размеров на разных платформах, etc.). Стоит о сериализации задуматься сразу.

Comment: @PavelSmirnov Не вижу там строгого требования оставить наследование. Автор пишет, что не хочет его убирать из-за: 1. эстетических соображений (которые в некотором смысле решаются концептами), и 2. желания проверять наличие метода (явно решается коцептами). Про более умную сериализацию - может и так, но не берусь советовать, не зная, что происходит в коде у автора.